# WCF Message contract versioning

Tags: wcf, messagecontract

I would like add a new **MessageBodyMember** to my **MessageContract** which refers to a new **Datacontract**.

Will there be an issue?.

What is the best way to handle message contract changes?.

How to know whether the addition of a new MessageBodyMember would be a breaking or non-breaking change?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Message contract versioning is handled in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx:

> Occasionally, you may need to change message contracts. For example, a
>   new version of your application may add an extra header to a message.
>   Then, when sending from the new version to the old, the system must
>   deal with an extra header, as well as a missing header when going in
>   the other direction.
>
> The following rules apply for versioning headers:
>
> - WCF does not object to the missing headers—the corresponding
>     members are left at their default values.
> - WCF also ignores unexpected extra headers. The one exception to
>     this rule is if the extra header has a MustUnderstand attribute set to
>     true in the incoming SOAP message—in this case, an exception is thrown
>     because a header that must be understood cannot be processed.
>
> **Message bodies have similar versioning rules—both missing and
>   additional message body parts are ignored.**

So that means that you can add and remove MessageBodyMembers, without breaking compatibility. Be careful with changing member types. Make sure they are serialized equally to remain compatible.